# Why does foreach return a list of lists

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm getting myself all tied in knots trying to understand what's going on with the code below. I'm trying to create a vector for each row in a data.frame then append to the original. I expected the code below to return a list of arrays. It appears to return a list of lists, the inner list contains the array? How can I get want I want - a new column appended each element being an array?

```
df <- mtcars 

library(foreach)
library(iterators)

df$x = foreach (row = iter(df, by='row'))  %do%  {
  profile <- as.numeric(row[,c('mpg', 'cyl', 'disp')])
  return(profile)
}
```

I'm expecting the result:

```
df[1,]$x == as.numeric(df[1,c('mpg', 'cyl', 'disp')])
```

instead I get

```
df[1,]$x[1] == as.numeric(df[1,c('mpg', 'cyl', 'disp')])
```

(where I'm using == to represent both collections are the same, I realize R probably doesn't implement a list equality operator this way)

Comment: I am not sure about the output you want to get. What do you expect to get from `df[1,]$x[1]`?

Comment: I'm trying to get df[1,]$x to return what df[1,]$x[1] does - i.e. as.numeric(row[1,c('mpg', 'cyl', 'disp')])

Comment: If you execute `str(df)` you'll see that `df$x` is a list of vectors, which is what foreach returns in your example. If you change the combine function to `rbind` then `df$x` will be a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `foreach` package by default returns a list of lists of your input (one list for each iteration). This is why you end up with the 'wrong' output. You can change this by using the `.combine` option in the foreach loop. If I understand you correctly, you wish to append row by row. This can be achieved by specifying `.combine = 'rbind'`, which uses the familiar `rbind` function to combine the outputs of each loop iteration. If the order is irrelevant, you should also specify `.inorder = FALSE` to speed up the code. (`TRUE` is default, so in case the order is relevant, you don't need to bother.)
So try using `foreach (row = iter(df, by='row'), .combine='rbind') %do% ...` instead and see if it does the job.

Comment: Thanks, this cbind doesn't work but rbind appears to. If I use rbind then I think the result is an array - i.e. the following works df[1,]$x * df[1,]$x (i.e. produces an element wise multiplication). I get confused because I'm not 100% sure in Rstudio how to check what type the result is i.e. typeof(df[1,]$x) says "double"

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out, I think I must have meant 'rbind', since 'cbind' does not make any sense for your problem - I edited the answer. glad I could help out! :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not caused by `foreach`. As you want to assign a vector to a cell (or element) of a data frame rather than a column of a data frame. The `foreach` function has to coerce this vector to a `list`.

For example.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x1=1:4, x2=letters[1:4], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1$x1[1] <- 5:8
# Warning message:
# In df1$x1[1] <- 5:8 :
#   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
df1
#   x1 x2
# 1  5  a
# 2  2  b
# 3  3  c
# 4  4  d
df1$x1[1] <- list(5:8)
df1
#           x1 x2
# 1 5, 6, 7, 8  a
# 2          2  b
# 3          3  c
# 4          4  d
df1$x1[1]
# [[1]]
# [1] 5 6 7 8
df1$x1[[1]]
# [1] 5 6 7 8
```

Actually, you should use `[[` instead of `[`.

```
df[1, ]$x[[1]] == as.numeric(df[1,c('mpg', 'cyl', 'disp')])
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

As `list[1]` is still a list while `list[[1]]` extracts the first element of `list`. See the example below.

```
lst1 <- list(x1=1:4, x2=letters[1:5])
lst1[1]
# $x1
# [1] 1 2 3 4
lst1[[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```

In addition, you can use:

```
df$x[[1]]
[1]  21   6 160
```

instead of:

```
df[1, ]$x[[1]]
# [1]  21   6 160
```

Comment: This is not the question.

Comment: Thanks but as @Pascal says I understand how to access the result, The question is why is foreach returning a list of lists and how do I make it return just a list

Comment: `foreach` returns a list rather than a list of lists.

Comment: foreach doesn't coerce anything to a list: it simply returns a list of vectors, as you say in your comment. But since mtcars doesn't have a column named "x", the assignment adds a new column that is a list. It's the same as executing `df1$x3 <- list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8)` in your example.

Comment: Thanks @SteveWeston that's was where I was getting confused, it's the behavior of the assignment of the result from foreach to the data.frame which was confusing me.